# Calculating the solution of OLS efficiently when adding one feature at a time

Tags: linear-regression, algorithms, linear-algebra

We know that the analytical solution for an OLS problem is $̂ =(^T)^{-1}^$. I am looking for an efficient algorithm to solve for $̂$ when I add one feature at a time. More specifically, I want to use the inverted matrix $^T$ in the previous step for calculating the invert in the current step when I add a column to the matrix  instead of calculating the inversion from the scratch each time. The only related post I have found is this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182309/block-inverse-of-symmetric-matrices) which when I implemented naively in python was numerically unstable.